# Autopep8: Custom Indent

Tags: python, autopep8

How can I keep AutoPep8 formatter in Python from formatting my custom indents?

**From this:**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title =         models.CharField()
    description =   models.TextField()
    price =         models.DecimalField()
    featured =      models.BooleanField()
```

**To that:**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField()
    featured = models.BooleanField()
```

Comment: Can you show autopep8 settings, please?

Comment: Please post code as [formatted text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189). Don't post it as [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7306999).

Comment: Changed it, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Add this to `settings.json`

```
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
        "ignore",
        "E11",
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [autopep8 configuration documentation](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/#configuration), if you have / create a `.pycodestyle`, `setup.cfg`, `tox.ini`, `.pep8` or `.flake8` file, you can configure it to ignore `E11` which is the indentation error.

```
[pycodestyle]
ignore = E11
```

Once you have one of those files with that configuration in, you can tell autopep8 to use it with the `--global-config` flag